# String prefix of requested length in golang working with utf-8 symbols

Tags: string, go, utf-8

Is there some elegant way to crop string and create pretty string prefixes in golang? I have this function for start:

```
func prettyCrop(in string, cropLength int) string {
    if len(in) < cropLength {
        return in
    } else {
        in = in[0:cropLength]
        in = strings.TrimRightFunc(in, func(r rune) bool {
            if r == ' ' {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
        return in + "…"
    }
}
```

It works good enough for english texts, but has problems with something more complicated. See this example:

```
prettyCrop("čřč čřč", 8) //čř?…
```

TrimRightFunc is not working as I expect here. I expect it to return `čřč`. Why is this function not returning valid utf-8 string? Is there a library for this? How can I fix it? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that slicing a `string` slices the UTF-8 encoded byte slice that represents the string, not the characters or `rune`s of the `string`; this also means that if the `string` contains characters that are represented by multiple bytes in UTF-8 encoding, slicing / cutting the `string` may result in an invalid UTF-8 encoded sequence.

Assuming `cropLength` means to be a character limit (and not a byte-count limit), you should first convert the `string` to a `[]rune`, and operate on that:

```
func prettyCrop(in string, cropLength int) string {
    in2 := []rune(in)
    if len(in2) < cropLength {
        return in
    } else {
        in2 = in2[:cropLength]
        in = strings.TrimRightFunc(string(in2), func(r rune) bool {
            if r == ' ' {
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
        return in + "…"
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
for i := 0; i < 7; i++ {
    fmt.Println(prettyCrop("čřč čřč", i))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tjgFuWndKg)):

```
…
č…
čř…
čřč…
čřč…
čřč č…
čřč čř…
```

**Performance notes:**

The above example is not "performance" friendly, because:

- It converts the whole `in` string to `[]rune`, it would be enough to just get its first `cropLength` runes with a `for range`.
- Calling `strings.TrimRightFunc()` requires to convert the `[]rune` back to `string`, and then again a string concatenation is performed to generate the result. This could be avoided by manually looping over the `[]rune`, and only create a single `string` that is returned.